# Best Practice for Mainframe Testing Environment to create QA, UAT

Tags: mainframe

I have been tasked with improving current environments to establish a SDLC which includes DEV, QA and UAT and in the middle of it all is a mainframe.

From a Windows and Linux standpoint creating these environments is easy using virtualization.  I understand that mainframe pioneered virtualization and that it can be configured many ways.

What I am curious about is what is the best practice to use when doing this with Mainframe systems.  Currently there are two LPARs, PROD and Non-PROD.  In Non-PROD there are many datasets and CICS's for groups to use, but no real standard is followed.

I would think it is best to have a LPAR for each environment, but that is cost prohibitive at this time.

This may not be the best place to ask this question and if not, it can be moved.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure where it could be moved to. Have you explained what you are trying to do to your technical support people? DEV, QA, UAT (and others) are no problem on the same LPAR, you segregate the datasets and RACF controls who can do what to what, and with what sign-on if necessary. That's a broad, unnuanced suggested, but you need to find out how your technical support people would like to do it.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  As I am starting to understand how the LPAR can be used and that DEV, QA and UAT can be run by segregate the datasets, your comment validates that.  Unfortunately there is only a single RACF and so segregation there is not possible, at least from what I am told.

Comment: You have been told something which is... wrong. Users for each environment would have log-ons which only allowed access to datasets belonging to that environment. Developers may be able to access more than one environment (typically the next up-the-line from DEV) and support can typically access all. There can be log-ons solely for controlled use to higher environments for developers. That's only one way to do it. RACF controls all that, there is no such thing as "only one RACF" because there will only be one RACF, if that meant anything.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill said it is certainly possible to do on a single LPAR and many sites have done 
precisely that.

Some general suggestions (all are very obvious):

1. Standardization is both your friend and necessary
2. Write Environment independent *code* (e.g. Rexx / clist / JCL) when ever possible. 
   For Rexx you can retrieve the environment from a file or ISPF variables.
3. Where Prod / Dev / QA are going to be different (e.g. JCL / Parmlibs / JCL etc), 
   write programs (Rexx / Rexx Edit macros's etc) to convert Production into Development / Qa.
   This will reduce production problems and save developer time. It also makes it easier to 
   create new environments when necessary.
4. Developer should work on **Production-ready-files** (JCL, parmlibs) and only *Production-ready-files*.  These *production-ready-files* files should  then be converted to the equivalent DEV, UAT files using automatic procedures (see 3)
5. Hopefully they are already many of these things on the mainframe

---

Some examples of what can be done,

For datasets, what you can do:

```
 Prod Name         Dev Name          QA       
 PSSS.blah.blah    DSSS.blah.blaf    QSSS.blah.blah
 PROD.blah2        DEV.blah2         QA.Blah2
```

individual users can be given access (RACF etc) based on there needs

For JCL, you can setup include's that define each environment
e.g.

```
//...  JOB ...
// INCLUDE MEMBER=PRODVARS 
//
//STEP01 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DEL01   DD  DSN=&ENV.SSS.BLAH,DISP=(MOD,DELETE)
```

Where PRODVARS sets ENV=P

You also need strategies for CICS / DB2 etc

---

Its a big area and far to broad for a single answer. But

- **it can be done**
- you can always ask questions about how to do specific area's

Comment: Brave shot at a huge area. Not clear to me what your No 4 means. Perhaps expand on the use of the JCL symbol for the high-level qualifier. Lots else could be included, but there's a 30,000-char limit on posts :-)

Comment: I have tried rewording, Really I was reinforcing 3. Developers should update JCL that is ready to go into Production and create the "Test" JCL from the "Production ready JCL". If you test your programs with "modified production JCL", come implementation time, you will not forget the "new" file you just added to the program.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. Anytime the JCL has to be "re-written" from what has been tested with is a frailty. Although often things aren't simple, symbolics and generation of JCL should always be able to guarantee the "same" JCL throughout the cycle.